# Prevent bootstrap dropdown from being split across lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with two columns. The first column has a lot of text, and the second column has a dropdown made with Twitter's bootstrap. I want the second column to take as little space as needed to display the dropdown **on a single line**. I want the first column to take the rest of the available width. So I set `width: 100%` on the first column, and `white-space: nowrap` on the second column.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/cberzan/hgCyD/3/

This does what I want in Chrome (Linux / 18.0.1025.151), but in Firefox (Linux / 11.0) and Opera (Linux / 11.64), the dropdown **gets split into two lines**:

[image: example]

How can I prevent the dropdown from being split?

Comment: Just so you know, Chrome (Windows 7) looks just fine.

Comment: Right; works for me in Chrome too, but not in Firefox / Opera :(

Comment: Sorry, read that wrong. Stuck with tables? I can't get anything to work either.

Comment: are you actually displaying a table of tabular data? if not you should ditch the tables

Comment: Looks like the bootstrap folks fixed it! https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3130